# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - using Generator

Tags: mysql, hibernate, primefaces

```
CREATE TABLE `examrequisitions` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `doctorId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `patientId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `examId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dateRequisition` datetime NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(7,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('Realized','Opened') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Opened',
  `obs` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `doctorId` (`doctorId`),
  KEY `patientId` (`patientId`),
  KEY `examId` (`examId`),
  CONSTRAINT `doctorId` FOREIGN KEY (`doctorId`) REFERENCES `doctors` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `examId` FOREIGN KEY (`examId`) REFERENCES `exams` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `patientId` FOREIGN KEY (`patientId`) REFERENCES `patients` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `reports` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('Validated','Invalidated') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Invalidated',
  `outcome` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `examrequisitions` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This following query is working:

```
INSERT INTO `systemcardiologyreports`.`reports` VALUES(1,'Invalidated', null);
```

But using Hibernate, trying to send the same values from the front end gives me: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`systemcardiologyreports`.`reports`, CONSTRAINT `id FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES`examrequisitions`(`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Model:

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign",
            parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "examrequisitions"))
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private Long id;

@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Examrequisitions examrequisitions;
```

Primefaces:

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateReportsLabel_examrequisitions}" for="examrequisitions" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="examrequisitions" value="#{reportsController.selected.examrequisitions}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateReportsRequiredMessage_examrequisitions}">
    <f:selectItems value="# examrequisitionsController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}" var="examrequisitionsItem" itemValue="#{examrequisitionsItem}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateReportsLabel_status}" for="status" />
<p:selectOneRadio id="status" value="#{reportsController.selected.status}">
     <f:selectItems value="#{reportsController.status}"  var="status" itemLabel="#{status}" itemValue="#{status}" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
<p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateReportsLabel_outcome}" for="outcome" />
<p:inputTextarea id="outcome" value="#{reportsController.selected.outcome}" title="#{bundle.CreateReportsTitle_outcome}" rows="7" maxlength="100" />
```

Comment: How is this JSF related?

Comment: See the edit please.

Comment: Are you sure its the same values hibernate is inserting? You can turn on logging of all sql in persistence.xml

Comment: So it works if you write a unittest? Then find what you do different. PrimeFaces does not store anything in a database, Hibernate does that. And **you** write a backingbean that uses entities. So still not PrimeFaces related